# EF Joins and MVC Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have several tables whose relationships are based upon unique key constraints.

A quick example is:

VersionId, VersionName
SurveyId, SurveyName, VersionId
QuestionId, QuestionName, SurveyId, VersionId

EF doesn't currently support relationships based upon unique key constraints.  In my index view for question what's the best way handle the join to survey to show the grid of questions with survey name with respect to a model?

Do I need an anonymous type? db.Questions.Include("Surveys") doesn't seem to do anything.  I could use linq and make a ViewModel of the joined tables (I suspect this is the way to go), but there are so many things in EF & MVC that I thought I'd check before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a link to Version (i.e. VersionID) in both your survey table and your question table?  Couldn't you reach the version from the question through the survey?

Also, if you have the relationship between Question and Survey is many-to-one or one-to-one (each question only has one survey) then it should be `db.Questions.Include("Survey")` - **non-plural**.

Comment: The easy answer to "why is version on question" is that there are other tables that are dependent on version that are linked to question.  In order to ensure that say, response is the appropriate version for the question, I need version on the question table itself.

Comment: When using "Include" for anything, I get no additional properties on the resulting entities...  I suspect this is because entity framework is not aware of unique key constraints, so it skips/ignores foreign keys based upon them.

Comment: I have the compound key to ensure referential constraints in the database itself.  Your question led me to make an EF association of just the relevant data.  And it worked like a champ!  Then I had to refresh my schema and I was thinking...  The redundant relationship wouldn't hurt in the database, so I added a bunch of relationships joining on just the single key instead of the compound key and BAM, everything is linked up with EF goodness.  Thanks for the inspiration :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no joins (or practically any other logic) in razors views. Controller is the place to build up the ViewModel, and  views are means to just present that ViewModel. As you mentioned, making `ViewModel` for it is only (correct) way to go. And you can fill that viewmodel by whatever method - linq is absolutely normal way to create joined data. And if you want to go further, you should place that join logic in some kind of repository, for example `QuestionRepository`, not in controller.

Comment: Ahh a question repository not a controller, I like that :-)  I've been trying my best to keep all logic relating to an entity in its associated controller...